# Advice for Spring Adaptation for an SAP connected intranet site

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

We have an intranet site that serves 50.000 users at maximum (generally only a couple of people is online at the same time). We use Eclipse, SAP Connector, J2EE 1.4, JSP, Struts 1.x, Tomcat 4.1, and SVN.

1- I want to modernize/rewrite the whole site with an easier structure and best-in-class software and techniques. What are your advices on this?

2- I'm planning to use "SpringSource Tool Suite" for this purpose, is this suitable? What else do I need? There are so many download options on the Spring download site, I'm confused, for example Spring Framework, Spring IDE, Spring Security etc. are all listed separately on the site, why? I have just downloaded "SpringSource Tool Suite" which is hundredths of megabytes in size, does it include all of them?

3- After installing Spring and all required tools, what type of project should I create
in Spring?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can use Spring with following module 
1. For presentation tier you will have Spring MVC

1. Upgrade the Tomcat version to latest stable version.
2. You also use Hibernate and JPA to increase performance at database level. -- In DAO tier
3. You can DOJO or DWR or JQuery for AJAX in presentation tier
4. You can do aspect oriented programming and use more annotation than code using spring core.

Comment: Many thanks Kamahire :) Is "SpringSource Tool Suite" is the right choice for me? I also consider using JQuery.

Comment: Since I'm a newby, I can't vote yet :( If accepting your answer close this question, I may not be able to see other responses, is it so? I don't know stackoverflow system very well.

Comment: I prefer waiting so that I can see other responses, your answer is good, I can accept it later, many thanks.

Comment: Sorry  for late reply. Spring Source tool, will be good choice if you choose Spring stack for developement. A